# How to replace with empty line in Caret?

Tags: sublime-text-2, chromebook, caret

I add unsuccessfully "\n" in the search. 
No regex seems to work. 
Caret is a clone of Sublime editor in Chromebook.

How can replace with empty line in Caret's search of Chromebook?

Comment: Did you enable `Regex Expression` for `Find` feature?

Comment: I think Caret is still different from Sublime, since I cannot find such a feature in settings.

Comment: Check this [doc](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html). On the screenshot button for enable it is marked red square

Comment: Ok, Caret is still behind. No such feature exists yet in the clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah now Caret doesn't have this feature. Bug I hope in nearest future it will be implemented.

You can subscribe on this **[issue](https://github.com/thomaswilburn/Caret/issues/454)** to be in touch about last updates.